# Why can't I install and use node packages

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am currently learning sass and I tried installing `SASS` using the command line. It gets installed but when I try out `sass --version` this is the error that I get:

```
sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the   
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sass --version
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This has happened before too, when I tried running a react project locally that used `yarn`. The same error came.

I think it is **because of the path that these commands are getting installed to**. After asking few people I discovered that for them `yarn` was installed in `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` but for me it was getting installed in `C:\usr\local\node_modules`, however I am not sure if this is the reason as I have tried moving the yarn folder manually to the correct path and that didn't seem to work as well.

I also saw that wrong **PATH variables** can also be the reason for this. Please share yours if you can and help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

well，if you don't install saas globally， you can use ./node_modules/.bin/sass

```
./node_modules/.bin/sass
```

or the npm script

```
{
"run" : "saas -h"
}
```